# Сколько ещё будет длиться русификация?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, профиль-участника

Текст явно "блещет".

> [image: профиль участника]

Как можно поучаствовать или хоть пожаловаться?

Comment: Никогда? Через 4 года, локализация всё ещё не окончена (в частности, из-за ошибочного дизайна локализации).

Answer (score 8):

Локализация будет длиться всегда. Можно рассчитывать, что через год-другой навоз из авгиевых конюшен будет на четверть вычищен в самых заметных местах.

Перевод был отдан паршивой безответственной компании, которая произвела *это*. Теперь *это* силами сообщества приводится в вид, которым *не очень* противно пользоваться. Так как поиском использования абсолютно всех строк в гуе никто не занимается, разрабы не удосужились прокомментировать контекст, строки под разные формы чисел добавляются от балды, а подавляющему большинству юзеров лень писать не Мету в случае обнаружения косяков, то нормальным перевод не будет никогда.

Если вопрос касается конкретно нелокализованных строк, то они тоже будут всегда. Сайт постоянно развивается, локализацией занимаются отдельные пользователи в свободное время, поэтому задержка с переводом гарантирована.

Чтобы поучаствовать, свяжитесь с [Николасом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6). Он на старой Мете Хэшкода раздавал доступ в Transifex.

Answer (score 8):

1. Пожаловаться можно, здесь же. Для жалобы откройте отдельный вопрос с метками [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) и [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), они обычно оперативно закрываются.
2. Принять участие тоже можно. Но корректная русификация — непростое занятие, так что скорее всего у вас не получится решить всё «одним махом». Поговорите с [Николасом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6).
3. Текст переводили такие же живые люди. Например, я. Кое-что мы не успели перевести, но вопрос стоял, запускать ли сайт с несовершенным переводом, или ждать, пока всё будет переведено? Как вы видите, если бы мы выбрали второй вариант, сайт до сих пор не был бы запущен.